# I had got the android source for 4.0.3, since then I've updated with repo to 4.0.4 . How can I work with 4.0.3 code instead?

Tags: android, git, repository, downgrade

I want to set repoy back to showing only code from 4.0.3 throughout the codebase.

Comment: There's probably not a huge difference between 4.0.4 and 4.0.3... just saying :)

Comment: I have an incompatibility specifically related to the 4.0.4 version, which is why I'm looking for it..

Comment: Are there tags for different versions?  If so, you could either checkout that tag, or reset to that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the help from everyone particularly buzeeg and R0MANARMY, figured it out.
The tags for android are listed at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest.git
and the command to actually switch to that tag, provided you have it already, is
        repo start  --all
only add the --all if you want the entire source changed over. Specify a particular packagename if you want just that changed.

Answer (score 0):

use **git hist** to look for the hash of your repo with old code.
then use **git checkout** with this hash to have in your folder the old version of the repository.

Comment: I don't have hist, trying the command directly from http://gitimmersion.com/lab_11.html results in
%s%d: command not found

Besides that, I want to set the entire android source back to the 4.0.3 version, not just one package.

Comment: Sorry : by hist, I meant log (yes i am using gitimmersion shortcuts :))

I am not sure to understand :-) have you all the android source in your git repo? Or is it just the link in your eclipse project which is broken ? In this case you might first change the target of your project in eclipse. Does it helps ?

Comment: I have the android source in my repo, it gets be a bit closer but doesn't solve the problem.